# Узнать версию удаленной OS

Tags: windows, bat, powershell

Есть удаленный компьютер, под какой-то версией Windows (начиная с WinXP Home и заканчивая Win10). Компьютер не входит в домен, но на нем установлен RAdmin Server.

Нужно определить версию и редакцию ОС.

Т.к. компьютеров много (~300), то нужно что-то автоматизированное.

Пробовал

```
(Get-WmiObject Win32_OperatingSystem -computer "Имя компа").name
```

но для недоменных компьютеров возвращает "Отказано в доступе (E_ACCESSDENIED)"

Может можно как-то заскриптовать работу с RAdmin?

**Update**

Удалось автоматизировать вход на удаленную машину через Radmin Telnet. Теперь вопрос - как получить редакцию ОС?

```
ver
```

возвращает

```
Microsoft Windows XP [Версия 5.1.2600]
```

а нужно еще редакцию Home или Professional

PowerShell на XP не установлен

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
wmic os get Caption,CSDVersion /value
```

или (но у меня systeminfo думает ну очень долго)

```
systeminfo | findstr /B /C:"OS Name" /C:"OS Version"
```

Источник: https://www.windows-commandline.com/find-windows-os-version-from-command/

Comment: Да. Я уже нашел эту ссылку. `wmic` у меня выдает `Дождитесь завершения установки WMIC.`, а `systeminfo` отрабатывает секунд 5. Можно и подождать. Только в фильтр нужно добавить еще и локализованные строки `Название ОС:`, `Версия ОС:` или использовать вместо `findstr` `for`

Comment: @AntonShchyrov, ну у меня оно _минут_ 5 отрабатывало. Я его нагуглил, запустил, надоело ждать, в ещё одной консоли проверил wmic, написал ответ, ещё подождал, отправил ответ, а systeminfo всё ещё выполнялся. Через некоторое время увидел вывод в консоли, промотал наверх и убедился в наличии нужных записей.

Comment: Сегодня проверил на реальной системе. На WinXP Home нет ни `systeminfo` ни `wmic`. Проблему решил выкладыванием systeminfo.exe от WinXP Pro  на FTP сервер и скачиванием файла на конкретную машину

Comment: @AntonShchyrov, тогда уж проще свою прогу сделать.

Answer (score 0):

Полный ответ выглядит так (решение на JScript)

1. Запускаем RadminViewer в режиме telnet

   ```
   var proc = WshShell.Exec('radmin.exe /connect:' + host + ' /telnet');
   ```
2. Ждем какое-то время и через `SendKeys` вбиваем логин и пароль соединения

   ```
   WScript.Sleep(1000);
   WshShell.AppActivate(proc.ProcessID);
   WshShell.SendKeys("user{TAB}");
   WshShell.SendKeys("pass{ENTER}");
   ```

   если в системе существует и третья и вторая версия Radmin (которая не требует имени пользователя), то можно использовать такой код

   ```
   WshShell.AppActivate(proc.ProcessID);
   // Три Shift+Tab
   WshShell.SendKeys("+{TAB}+{TAB}+{TAB}");
   // Если у нас вторая версия, то мы стоим на поле для ввода пароля
   WshShell.SendKeys("pass");
   // Переместились на предыдущий контрол
   WshShell.SendKeys("+{TAB}");
   // для второй версии мы попали на кнопку "Отмена", для третьей на поле для ввода пароля
   WshShell.SendKeys("pass");
   // Переместились на предыдущий контрол
   WshShell.SendKeys("+{TAB}");
   // для второй версии мы попали на кнопку "OK", для третьей на поле для ввода логина
   WshShell.SendKeys("user");
   WshShell.SendKeys("{ENTER}");
   ```
3. Делаем паузу на установку соединения и на удаленной машине формируем bat-файл

   ```
   WScript.Sleep(1000);
   WshShell.AppActivate(proc.ProcessID);
   // Получение информации и сохранение ее в info.data
   cmd('echo systeminfo ^> info.data >> info.bat');
   // На WinXP Home нет файла systeminfo, поэтому если вызов завершился неудачно
   cmd('if errorlevel 1 ( >> ' + cmdFile);
     // скачиваем его с FTP сервера
     cmd('echo ftp -s:get.ftp -n ' + ftpServer + ' >> info.bat');
     cmd('echo expand systeminfo.cab systeminfo.exe >> ' + cmdFile);
     cmd('echo systeminfo ^> ' + datFile + ' >> ' + cmdFile);
     cmd('del systeminfo.exe >> ' + cmdFile);
     cmd('del systeminfo.cab >> ' + cmdFile);
   cmd(')>> ' + cmdFile);
   // Сжимаем полученный файл
   cmd('echo makecab info.data info.data.cab >> info.bat');
   // И отправляем его с удаленной машины по FTP
   cmd('echo ftp -s:info.ftp -n ' + ftpServer + ' >> info.bat');
   ```
4. Формируем набор команд для скачивания файла с FTP

   ```
   cmd('echo USER ftp_user ftp_pass >> get.ftp');
   cmd('echo GET systeminfo.cab >> get.ftp');
   cmd('echo QUIT >> get.ftp');
   ```
5. Формируем набор команд для закачивания файла на FTP

   ```
   cmd('echo USER ftp_user ftp_pass >> info.ftp');
   cmd('echo PUT info.data.cab >> info.ftp');
   cmd('echo QUIT >> info.ftp');
   ```
6. Запускаем полученный bat-файл

   ```
   cmd("info.bat");
   ```
7. И закрываем сессию

   ```
   cmd("exit");
   ```

Функция `cmd()` определена так

```
function cmd(command) {
  WshShell.SendKeys(command.replace(/[\^%+~\(\)]/g, "{$&}") + "{ENTER}");
  WScript.Sleep(100);
}
```

Единственный минус метода - невозможность получить статус соединения от radmin

С учетом того обстоятельства, что команды `systeminfo` нет в редакциях WinXP Home и его приходится заливать вручную, целесообразнее написать свою утилиту, которая скачается с FTP сервера и выполнит все необходимые манипуляции